# When using Java classes from Jython, do you bother to use the getters and setters? Should you?

Tags: java, jython

It's well known that Python classes cannot have *truly* private members. The not-*as*-obvious implication of this is that Java classes' privates are made public to Jython. (Hide thy nakedness, Java!)

So, when using Jython, and accessing a Java classes' privates that would usually be exposed to other Java classes through getters and setters, do you bother to use those methods? Or do you just access the privates directly?

The more pertinent question would be, **should** you use the getters and setters? If there are side-effects of the methods, then the answer would undoubtedly be 'yes', but if the methods are just there because someone thought that a putting getters and setters everywhere is The Right Thing to do (IMO it's not, just make the damn thing public), then is there any reason to bother with all of Java's extra ceremony?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although Jython can make non-public Java members accessible from everywhere, [this is a feature that must be enabled explicitly](http://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq/ProgrammingJython#I.27m_trying_to_execute_a_.27protected.27_or_.27private.27_Java_Instance_Method_or_attribute_in_a_Java_package._How_can_I_get_access.3F). This alone is reason enough for me to honor the visibility of Java classes, otherwise you are risking *works on my machine* problems.

More principially, you should use the provided property accessors for classes that are not under your control unless you have a very good reason not to: You never know if future versions of the class will do more than just the bare minimum in their getters/setters.

Jython has the nice feature of [hiding the accessor methods of JavaBean properties](http://wiki.python.org/jython/UserGuide#javabean-properties).  Jython converts  `x.foo += 5` into `x.setFoo(x.getFoo() + 5`. Because usually the backing field of a property has the same name as the property itself, you may have confused this feature with "Jython makes the backing field accessible" even if it does not. I would definitively use this property-accessed-like-fields syntax of Jython: it makes your code more concise and easier to read.

Comment: That depends on your environment. [Pydev by default does not respect Java accessibility](http://www.mail-archive.com/pydev-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg03681.html), for the purpose of getting extra debug info. Not coming from a Java background, I actually didn't realise I was doing this for quite a while. Also, this is a feature you *have* to enable if your Jython subclass needs access to its parent class's protected fields.

Comment: That said, you're probably right about using the accessors of classes that aren't under my control. Thanks for the tip about hiding the accessors though, I didn't know that :)

Comment: One last point: Any sane person using Swing from Jython will surely be violating the Swing classes' accessibility all over the place already: `btn = JButton("Foo", actionPerformed = Bar)`, where Bar is a function, is a lot more concise and pythonic than `btn = JButton("Foo"); btn.addActionListener(bar)`, where bar is some object of a class that implements the ActionListener interface.

Comment: @CamJackson: The actionPerformed=... instead of addActionListener is actually another Jython shortcut for Listener-based events: http://wiki.python.org/jython/UserGuide#event-properties

Comment: Yeah I found that just after a wrote the comment, that's handy! For variables though, if Jython is always calling the accessors automatically when I access the private attributes directly, doesn't that make my original question essentially a non-issue, because the same thing will happen behind the scenes either way?

Comment: @CamJackson I was trying to communicate that it is likely that you are taking advantage of Jython's syntactic sugar for JavaBeans - and therefore it is a non-issue. So - yep, it's essentially a non-issue.